# Inserting rows and columns allowed in protect sheet but still warning message popups, how to stop that?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have following code to protect my sheet

```
Sub Lock_RESULT_SHEET ()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("RESULT").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="ABCD"
ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False



ActiveSheet.Range("A3:E5000").Locked = True


ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ABCD", Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True,AllowInsertingRows:=True,AllowInsertingColumns:=True

END SUB
```

## WHAT IS PROBLEM?  ## Here in the code I do have allowed row as well as column insert but while i insert it warning pop up appears that "the cell or chart you are trying to change is on protected sheet"
VBA expersts, Help me on this. thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `application.displayalerts = false` help? (turn them back on before exiting)

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need to add, as @Jeeped mentioned before. Make sure things you mark under `Application.X = False` is eventually set back to `= True`

```
Sub Lock_RESULT_SHEET ()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("RESULT").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="ABCD"
ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False



ActiveSheet.Range("A3:E5000").Locked = True


ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ABCD", Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True,AllowInsertingRows:=True,AllowInsertingColumns:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

END SUB
```